# My Android Studio2.2 cannot create cpp or c files

Tags: android, android-studio

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.The right-click option is missing new cpp/c

[image: The right-click option is missing new cpp/c]

How should I modify my AS settings?
The normal one maybe should like this:
[normal one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3nHx.png)

Answer (score 2):

Android studio Supports NDK ([Android Studio Native Support](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html))

You can create C++ module with the android studio.

N.B.: Android Studio is not intended for C/ C++ development.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, when I was in creating this project, I have already added the c++ support and download the NDK.But AS can not correctly identify the cpp files.(https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) also includes the operation like right click to create cpp and c file, but I 
 cannot do that in my project .What's problem with my AS